# Converting datestring from request to MySQL compatible date format

Tags: php, ajax, date, request, php-carbon

I am getting a date as a string from an Ajax call: `"Wed Jun 17 2020 09:26:45 GMT+0200 (Mitteleurop\u00e4ische Sommerzeit)"` and tried to format it in `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` but failed. I tried

```
$my = $request->input('date');
$date = Carbon::parse($my);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($my));
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $my);
$date = Carbon::create(my);
```

but nothing worked. Carbon works and `$request->input('date')` exists. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

As PHP would not handle every possible timezones in every possible languages, `Mitteleurop\u00e4ische Sommerzeit` make `Carbon::parse` but `GMT+0200` is enough for the timezone of 1 particular moment, so you can remove the extra timezone:

```
$my = $request->input('date');
$my = preg_replace('/\s*\(.*\)$/', '', $my);
$date = Carbon::parse($my);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($my));
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $my);
$date = Carbon::create(my);
```

Still you should consider this is a work-around. The correct approach is to send dates with a ISO string (in GMT timezone), and a clean timezone such as `Europe/Berlin` in an other field if the timezone matters.